# How do I know the difference of days, months, and years from a date, can I use subtraction?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm writing an algorithm where I'm going to get a whole number and with that I want to determine a date to expire a certain content. I'm already getting the date that the content was published.

Example:

publication date: 01/05/2019
days to expire: 30
result of the program: 01/06/2019 // date of expiry of the content

NOTE: The value of "Days to expire" is entered by the user.

How can I solve this? Do you have any documentation or function to help me?

Comment: `days_to_expire = 30; fmt =  '%d/%m/%Y'; (DateTime.strptime('01/05/2019', fmt).to_date + days_to_expire).strftime(fmt) #=> "31/05/2019"`. This returns the day before that given in the question. I assume that's do to a counting issue. Please edit to clarify the date you wish to compute.

Comment: `01/05/2019` and `01/06/2019` are not valid Ruby objects. Yes, I know what you mean, at least by the first (presumably the string `"01/05/2019"`), but I don't know if you mean the latter to be the string  `"01/06/2019"` or the `Date` object that represents that string. Be precise! If a value is string, enclose it in quotes. It would be better to write something like this: `publication_date = "01/05/2019"` and `days_to_expire =  30`.

Comment: @laurenzAlbe - please do not translate someone else's post (this has been discussed on Meta - see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/272109)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a handful of ways to accomplish what you're trying to do -- Here are a few possibilities.

Using `Time` (my recommendation so you have more flexibility later depending on how your needs change and how you end up expiring content):
You can convert the "days to expire" to seconds and then add that to your time object.  For example:

```
require "time"

t = Time.parse("01/05/2019")
days_to_expire = 30
expiration = t + (60 * 60 * 24 * days_to_expire)
```

Using `Date`:

```
require "date"

d = Date.parse("01/05/2019")
days_to_expire = 30
expiration = d + days_to_expire
```

Using built-in helpers from Rails `Active::Support`:

```
t = Time.parse("01/05/2019")
days_to_expire = 30
expiration = t + days_to_expire.days
```

You can learn more about Ruby `Time` [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Time.html#method-i-2B) and you can learn about the helpers built-in to `Time` and `Numeric` by Rails [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html) and [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Numeric.html).

Comment: Did you test your answer? If you must use `parse` why not `Date::parse` to avoid the roundabout conversion to time and adding seconds? Note the return value required is neither a `Time` nor `Date` object.

Comment: I did test my answer, and the question is asking for general guidance on date/time manipulation: "I'm going to get a whole number and with that I want to determine a date to expire a certain content [and] How can I solve this? Do you have any documentation or function to help me?". The example they give is a simplified version of what they are asking. Using `Date` in this case may be less confusing, though either work fine in helping push towards understanding how to solve the broader problem and using `Time` allows for more specificity.

Comment: The reason I asked about testing is that Ruby does not have a method `Time::parse` (`DateTime.parse` must be used, then `.to_date` or `.to_time`, as needed). Perhaps Rails has a method `Time::parse`. My main point is that, to obtain a date from a date, it's easier to add `30` to a `Date.parse(...)` than to add the corresponding number of seconds to a `Time.parse(...)`.

Comment: Ruby does have a method `Time::parse` https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-parse

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer this assuming the project is in Rails since this question is tagged as a Rails one. You could do something like this:

```
t = Date.parse("01/05/2019")
days_to_expire = 30   # Obtained from user input in your case
result = t + days_to_expire.days   # Similar to result = t + 30.days
```

You could check out more about `Date` [in the API docs here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html)

Comment: Why `DateTime.parse` rather than `Date.parse`? Ruby requires `DateTime.parse.to_date` to then add `30`. Does Rails not? Note that `DateTime.parse("You may find that 'parse' does not always give the result you expect") #=> #<DateTime: 2019-05-01T00:00:00+00:00, ((2458605j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> `. Better to use `strptime`.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I was unaware of `DateTime.parse` not being accurate all the time. I'd decided to suggest `DateTime` instead of `Date` because I had incorrectly assumed that the OP may need time specific calculations as well. I'll update the answer to use `Date`. Thanks!